# SQL code in VB MS Access inserts the new records to the middle of the table, not at the botom

Tags: ms-access, sql-insert

In MS Access, I need to insert new records using SQL code.
I wrote the following code in VB and it inserts the code to the middle of the table.
Is there any chance to find out the reason?

```
sql = "INSERT INTO Audit_riskModelHistory (Action, User, modelKey, modelEventKey) " & _
"VALUES ('New Record Inserted', 'Mike-Admin', " & _
Me.cmb1.Value & ", " & Me.cmb2.Value & ")"
    
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL (sql)
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
```

I tried looking at the properties of the table but I did not find the reason.

Comment: Tables in Access do not have any innate order, only what is applied by sorting. There is no reason to worry about the order that data appears in a table.

Comment: If you want to retrieve the records in some particular order, add a field to the table that will store the sequence information, and use order by in the retrieval to order it the way you want.  Note that the Primary Key feature already does this for you, except that this may not be the order you want.

Comment: You say VB but I think it is actually VBA. Add appropriate tag.